# Cannot find module _frozen_importlib_external when running a frozen exe program

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

Hi I am pretty new to cx_Freeze, so when I try to freeze a Python file (it's just a basic hello world program) cx_Freeze creates an exe along with a bunch of other things. When I run the exe it gives me a "cannot find module _frozen_importlib_external" error. I am using Python 3.5 and running Windows 10. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The issue here is that cx_freeze can't see the import and will not embed the package `_frozen_importlib_external`.

Change the file cx_Freeze/finder.py with the diff given at https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-requests/83/python-35-compatibility-for-cx_freeze-4x/diff and then build and install cx_Freeze again.

Comment: Noob question, but how do I build cx_Freeze? Thanks for the help, too.

Comment: You can basically download the source code directly from the pypi website. Choose the tar.gz file. Then unpack it, replace finder.py with the corrected version, repack the directory, and then use ```pip install``` on the new packed directory. I'm not sure it's a clean way to do it, but it works.

Comment: I have the same problem, but changing finder.py did not change the result.